# What category does questions like "Given n points on 2D plane find ..." belong to

Tags: terminology

Not after a specific answer, do following questions belong to same set of problem types?

Given n points in on 2D plane, find 4 or 5 , or m subset of points with less total distant to each other than all other points.

Or

Given n points in on 2D plane, count the number of triangles, squares etc. that they form.

Or

Given n points in on 2D plane, find a point that is closeses to most number of points as possible.

are these optimisation questions? or is there another name for above type of questions, or there can be no category for all the questions of type

Given n points in on 2D plane, find $\cdots$

This question did not seem to be fit for SO or Software engineering, so I am asking it here, if there is better SE to ask this question I'll delete this question and ask it there ( in reverse order ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinatorial geometry.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CombinatorialGeometry.html

Computational geometry.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry